# How can I use iOS Swift SKOverlay with UIKit to cross promote another app?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'd like to cross promote another app in my UIKit-based app (e.g. no SwiftUI).

SKOverlay was added in iOS 14 but seems to be targeted at SwiftUI based apps

I've read about how to do it here, https://sarunw.com/posts/cross-promote-apps-with-skoverlay/ but the suggested UIKit approach is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, you can use UIKit example in https://sarunw.com/posts/cross-promote-apps-with-skoverlay/ but call the displayOverlay() method in viewDidLoad, otherwise the windowScene is not yet created.